# How to validate a salesforce react input component?

Tags: reactjs, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

The salesforce lightning design system [documents](https://react.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/inputs/#prop-onInvalid) an `onInvalid` callback for the `Input` component.  It does not appear to provide any examples though.

I have tried something similar to the following code.  When I change the input to an invalid value, for example 2, then the error handler is not executed.

```
<Input type='number'
       minValue={3}
       value={someValue}
       onChange={someChangeHandler}
       onInvalid={someErrorHandler} />
```

How can I use `onInvalid` to validate an input?

Any examples of the correct usage would be appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that `min` should be `minValue` ? There is no `min` prop on the element you linked to

Comment: Well spotted, yes, I'm actually using `minValue`. `onInvalid` still does not execute though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `minValue` is used to define the range of a counter `Input` together with `maxValue`.

You can use `onChange` to test the current input against your custom validation and set a Boolean `isError` state variable that you can use to conditionally set some errorText.

Comment: Apologies, I should have been clearer. What you've described is more or less what I am doing at the moment.  What I would like to know is how to use the `onInvalid` prop specifically.  I've edited my post to make that clear.